How to call a variable inside dynamic SQL Query in Snowflake stored procedure
Need help to call variable inside snowflake stored procedure. It throws a "Missing column specification" - how to access variable allcols inside dynamic SQL in snowflake?
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TES()
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
DECLARE 
    
    allcols VARCHAR(16777216);
 
    sql_text_test VARCHAR(16777216);
    
BEGIN

           SELECT LISTAGG( '''' || NAME || '''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) 
            INTO :allcols
            FROM(SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM PARSEDNUM UNION SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM PARSEDCHAR) 
           AS NAMES;

         sql_text_test := ' 
                CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE TEST as 
                    select
                        a.DATA_KEY_ as DATA_KEY_, 
                         ' || allcols || '
                        
                    from transposednum AS a 
                    left join transposedchar AS b
                    on a.DATA_KEY_ = b.DATA_KEY_
                
            ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text_test;```
          
    RETURN 'Table  created successfully';

END;
$$;


Temporarily change your SP to return sql_text_test (and don't execute it) and then you'll be able to see the actual statement being run and debug it

Still gave same error and I tried set allcols and calling them in sql,    SET allcols = (
SELECT LISTAGG('''' || NAME || '''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM PARSEDNUM
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM PARSEDCHAR
) AS NAMES
);  Now this throws below error Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 28 at position 12 : Assignment to 'ALLCOLS' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 1,768;

i tried this and was able to execute, let me know if this is what you wanted.
    create table PARSEDNUM(name char(2000)) ;
create table PARSEDCHAR(name char(2000));
insert into PARSEDNUM values('PARSEDNUM');
insert into PARSEDNUM values('PARSEDCHAR');

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TES()
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
DECLARE 
    
    allcols VARCHAR(16777216);
 
    sql_text_test VARCHAR(16777216);
    
BEGIN

           SELECT LISTAGG( '''' || NAME || '''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) 
            INTO :allcols
            FROM(SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM PARSEDNUM UNION SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM PARSEDCHAR) 
           AS NAMES;

         sql_text_test := ' 
                CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE TEST as 
                    select
                        a.DATA_KEY_ as DATA_KEY_, 
                         ' || :allcols || '
                        
                    from transposednum AS a 
                    left join transposedchar AS b
                    on a.DATA_KEY_ = b.DATA_KEY_
                
            ';
      --      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_text_test;```
          
    RETURN sql_text_test;

END;
$$;

 call SP_TES();

The above execution returns the following statement,
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE TEST as
select
a.DATA_KEY_ as DATA_KEY_,
'PARSEDCHAR','PARSEDNUM'
                    from transposednum AS a 
                    left join transposedchar AS b
                    on a.DATA_KEY_ = b.DATA_KEY;

I created a table as follows,
create  table transposednum (DATA_KEY_ char(200));
create or replace table transposedchar (DATA_KEY char(200));
It returns error on the "'PARSEDCHAR','PARSEDNUM'" , are they the new columns that you will create or they are existing in the table  transposednum  or transposedchar  ?
If you want to create table on the basis of columns in the PARSEDCHAR or PARSEDNUM table then you can use the column_name from information_schema.columns views.

This still throws same missing column specification

Please check the edited answer and what are the values in the PARSEDNUM and PARSEDCHAR tables ?

If possible, can you post the table structure and sample data in the tables used in the procedure.

Thanks Himanshu, I am able to retrieve column headers from the temp table, when trying to select column  I am not getting all columns with values.I believe , I am missing a portion of the code.Let me post as new comment .
